# React Native: Issue with FlatList - Dynamic Data Rendering Problem

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently facing an issue with the FlatList component in my React Native project. The list is not rendering dynamically when the data changes. Here's a simplified version of my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, FlatList, Text, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([1, 2, 3]);

  const handleAddItem = () => {
    const newItem = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    setData([...data, newItem]);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Text>{item}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
      <Button title="Add Item" onPress={handleAddItem} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Despite using the setData function to update the state with a new item, the FlatList does not render the added item. The console.log inside the handleAddItem function shows that the state is updating correctly.

Can someone please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this problem with the FlatList not rendering dynamically when the data changes? Any insights or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to provide some sample minimal code to test it out on some ide's like https://codesandbox.io/ ?I can guess the issue but it would be like doing brute force.